# Mouse Listener ,detect File Mouse Over in Explorer

Tags: c#, fileinfo, mouse-listeners

Im working on a Project which Handles with File information's ,like Tool-tips File Attributes etc.
So my question is can i integrate and does anyone yet ,a Mouse Listener if Mouse is Over a File in Windows Explorer or Desktop ,so in that way i can Show a tool-tip and handle with other Function's.

PS: I need the FileName (Full Path with File Name) which Mose is Over on it.

Comment: Avoid using C# in Explorer. It requires a .Net VM. It's a process-wide decision which .Net VM you'll use, and you cannot decide as a plug-in that all other plug-ins should also use .Net 2.0. BTW, Explorer uses PIDLs not file paths to identify items; many items shown in Explorer aren't even files but they all have PIDLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ghacks.net/2008/02/10/customize-windows-explorer-tooltips/ lists a way of changing the tooltips when mousing over a file.
If you want to do anything more advanced like running a custom program on mouseover then you'll probably need to look at either rethinking why you need to do it (suggested), or doing something ugly with hooking mouse messages using e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I want to get the File Name with the Full Path ,the File which Mouse is Over.

Comment: Why? What part of the application needs that, and can you do it a better way?

Comment: on Mouse over i want to Display some File Attributes and a Button in Tool-tip where user can decide if he/she want's to Import that File .

Comment: Either do it in program (let them choose files to import, then since it's in program you can show whatever you want), or just settle for a context menu entry.
A much nicer solution than hooking everything the user does, adding additional overhead, in order to annoy them with windows popping up.